# AngularJS check if promise is empty or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-resource

Hi I have this code for the purpose of checking if there are users in the database, if it finds shows a list of users on a view, otherwise shows a view with form of user creation, but didn't work the check expression what I'm doing wrong

```
users = Users.query();

users.$promise.then(
    function (data) {
        if (!data) {
            $location.url('/NewUser')
        } else {
            $location.url('/UsersList')
        }

    });
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the code and seeing what the **data** object contains?

Comment: What is it that is is doing? Is the check always true/false? Is the data a truthy value like an empty array etc?

Comment: @ste2425 yes is what I'm trying to do but seems this is not the answer

Answer (score 2):

It is probably returning an empty array in case nothing is found. Try checking the data length.

```
if (data.length == 0) {
   $location.url('/NewUser')
} else {
   $location.url('/UsersList')
}
```

Comment: this, or check for a specific attribute of the data to be defined